# Force close port 22 (ssh) on GCP VM

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security, firewall

For security reasons, I want to close port 22 (ssh) of my VM that is on GCP.
Currently, if I execute the command `telnet xx.xx.xxx.xxx 22` the server responds to me:

```
Trying xx.xx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to xx.xx.xxx.xxx.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
```

I tried configuring correctly the firewall rules that are in contact with the VM: Remove "apply to all" from the target in the "default-allow-ssh" rule and create a rule called "close-ssh" that denies all connections to the port 22 since 0.0.0.0/4.
Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LGkW.png

Also I verified that running the `sudo iptables -L` command on the server does not find any rules that expose port 22. The output was as follows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Y al ejecutar el comando `nmap -p 22 xx.xx.xxx.xxx` tengo el siguiente output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-05-10 09:56 -03
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xxx.xxx.bc.googleusercontent.com (xx.xx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.32s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.67 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want sshd running at all?
I don't see any rule in iptables blocking tcp 22

Shut down sshd if you don't need it.

Try adding a rule like
DROP ssh -- anywhere anywhere

You can always add an "accept ssh -- from to" if you want to allow specific access.

Comment: Hello! It is a good idea! But if I stop the "ssh" service, it is not possible to connect from the GCP CLI

Comment: That's why I asked if you want sshd running at all. Since you do, don't shut it down. But do add a DROP rule as suggested and also an ACCEPT rule for the specific source(s) you want to allow to that destination

Comment: Okay! I understand now. But should I create an ACCEPT rule for each developer IP that will connect?

Comment: Create an ACCEPT rule for each IP source you want to allow